# How to calculate age in JavaScript with the format dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: javascript, html

How to take user input in the dd/mm/yyyy format and use it to calculate the user's age?

```
function userAge() {
  var todayDate = new Date().getMilliseconds;
  var birthDateSplit = document.getElementById("birthDate").split('/');
  var birthDate = new Date(birthDateSplit[2],birthDateSplit[1],birthDateSplit[0]);
  var day = birthDate[2]*86400000;
  var month = birthDate[1]*2629746000;
  var year = birthDate[0]*31556952000;
  var age = today - (day + month + year);

  return age;
}
```

Comment: What is in `today`?

Comment: You probably men `.getElementById("birthDate").value.split(...)`

Comment: Look at the developer tools.... It will tell you why it returns nothing. There are errors. Learn to debug.

Comment: @thezeroandone The issue is the code above does not work because you have errors in it. The developer console should be telling you about the errors. Open up the developer console in the browser and look at the error messages. (and yes, the way you are doing it is flawed)

Comment: @thezeroandone ah ah I see, sorry the comma threw me off :)

Answer (score 3):

We can solve this in two ways:

1. You can use [javascript dates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) if you don't want to go for plugins.

Take value from the field, and formulate it as a date.

```
var birthDayDate = document.getElementById("birthDate").value;
var from = birthDayDate.split("/");
var birthdateTimeStamp = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]);
```

**Code Sample:**

```js
var from = "15/09/1994".split("/");
var birthdateTimeStamp = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]);
var cur = new Date();
var diff = cur - birthdateTimeStamp;
// This is the difference in milliseconds
var currentAge = Math.floor(diff/31557600000);
// Divide by 1000*60*60*24*365.25

console.log(currentAge);
```

2. You can do it with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) in a single line - you have cdn & npm for it.

```
var birthDayDate = document.getElementById("birthDate").value;
const ageInYears = moment().diff(new Date(birthDayDate), 'years');
console.log(ageInYears);
```

```js
const years = moment().diff(new Date('1981/01/01'), 'years');
console.log(years);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @thezeroandone, done, added javascript date solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `Date` constructor will handle parsing your user input.  Then you can use `getTime()` to get the millisecond time.

```
function userAge() {
  var todayDate = new Date().getTime();
  var birthDate = new Date(document.getElementById("birthDate")).getTime();
  var age = (todayDate - birthDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)

  return age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The age is current_year - yyyy.

Then -1 if the mm>current_month 
or mm==current_month and dd>current_day.